# Nav Link on react-router-dom latest version is not working

Tags: reactjs

Im new to react. I guess and I think NavLink does not work any longer at react router dom latest version. May I ask what can be the replacement for NavLink? Thankyou in advance I know this is a repetitive question but none of those solutions worked for me so I tried posting question.

Btw, the error occuring is something like this when i tried to run the react app. "Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a Router component."

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";


export default function navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
      <a className="navbar-brand">Hotel Booking App</a>
      <button
        className="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul className="navbar-nav">
          <li className="nav-item active">
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/Register">
            Register
          </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="/login">
              Login
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have imported and used **NavLink** correctly.
There have to be routes defined in your application in order to use **NavLink**. I am not sure If you have defined routes for your application. You may define your routes in react this way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Test_1 from './components/Test_1';
import Test_2 from './components/Test_2';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Test_1 />} />
          <Route path='/home' element={<Test_2 />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Okay i will try this later, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you need to wrap the component at the top level with BrowserRouter